# how to test if route return true/false on specific params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a simple login function:

```
def login
  @user = User.find_by_email params[:email]
  if @user
    if  BCrypt::Password.new(@user.encrypted_password).is_password? params[:password]
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
      render json: true
    else
      render json: false
    end
  else
    render json: false
  end
end
```

and I want to test if this function actually will return false if user does not exist I have created the following test:

```
  def test_my_action
    post :login, :format => 'json',  :email => 'foo@bar.com', :password => 'test'
    assert_response json:false
  end
```

I know that assert_response will return status 200 or other, but I cant figure out how to create the necessary assert.

How do I test if my login function actually return false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for a JSON response using RSpec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159882/how-to-check-for-a-json-response-using-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the @infused link, there will be problem to you to parse the 'response.body' because it is a string.
You can do it like this

```
response.body.should eq('false')
```

or

```
response.body.should eq('true')
```

But I would like to suggest that render json with {key => value} pair.