# rspec test not saving db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just added a new function to my model and wanted to tested with rspec. It seems as if i'm doing something wrong because my test keep failing and nothing is being stored at the db. What I want is to have the hability to, as a user, block another user.

My user model has the following:

```
  has_many :blockeds
  has_many :blocked_users, :through=> :blockeds
```

My user_controller has the following:

```
def block
      block_action = Blocked.new
      block_action.add_blocked(current_user.id,params[:id])
      current_user.blockeds << User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def is_blocked
      blocked = current_user.blocked_by(current_user.id,params[:id])
      blocked
    end
```

my Blocked model has the following:

```
belongs_to :user_blocking, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user_blocked, class_name: 'User'

  def add_blocked(blocking_id,blocked_id)
    self.user_blocking_id = blocking_id
    self.user_blocked_id = blocked_id
    self.save!
  end
```

and this is my test:

```
describe 'Block' do

    let(:user_one) { Fabricate :user }
    let(:user_two) { Fabricate :user }

    it 'should block a user' do
      post :block, current_user: user_one.to_param, id: user_two.id.to_param, format: :json
      expect{
        post :is_blocked, current_user: user_one.to_param, id: user_two.id.to_param, format: :json
      }.to eq(user_two)
    end
  end
```

I wanted to test if user_two was blocked by user_one. Nothing being stored at the db neither. any help?

This is what i get after i excecute the test:

```
expected: #<User id: 2, email: "arden@hotmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$cKnZx8h9nVX1xQOruH6.yeSHIl989EA.amK.fqz4kwz...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-12-23 13:48:32", updated_at: "2014-12-23 13:48:32", bio: nil, fb_access_token: "accusamuscumsit", fb_app_id: "essesedmaiores", phone: nil, address: nil, authentication_token: "vH3N1KTz1AVmP8fTRAye", gender: "male", profile_completed: false, zip_code: "95304-2111", state: "Indiana", city: "New Chaunceymouth", latitude: 37.6841772, longitude: -121.3770336, access_code_id: nil, locked_at: nil, cover: nil, fb_global_id: nil, birthday: "1996-02-18", age: 226, channel_id: "mh3_dPdbihISTdX8TCOKkQ", first_name: "Tressa", last_name: "Keeling", access_code_type: nil, facebook_data_updated_at: nil>
            got: #<Proc:0x00000107fafd68@/Users/toptierlabs/Documents/projects/kinnecting_backend/spec/controllers/api/users_controller_spec.rb:206>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a block to `expect`, which is intended to be used in situations where you want to evaluate how the execution of that block changes the environment (e.g. via `to_change`). It's typically executed in the context of a transaction, but in your case it's not being executed at all since you're just using it with the `eq` matcher.

If you want to check the value returned by a controller operation, you need to check the value of `response` as in:

```
post :is_blocked, current_user: user_one.to_param, id: user_two.id.to_param, format: :json
expect(response.body).to eq(user_two.to_json)
```

See [How to check for a JSON response using RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159882/how-to-check-for-a-json-response-using-rspec) for more on this.