# How to to check correct Title is present in JSON by connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to `Rspec`. How to write controller code to connect to `localhost:3000/v.json` link in `Rspec` and check the title is as expected?

```
JSON format is  {id: 1, title: "new"}
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for a JSON response using RSpec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159882/how-to-check-for-a-json-response-using-rspec)

Comment: How to connect to the link(URL)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a functional test of your controller, that hits your action, with something like this:

```
@expected = { 
  id: 1,
  title: "new"
}.to_json

# replace with action name / params as necessary, perhaps also passing "id: 1"?
get :v, format: "json"
response.body.should == @expected
```

Comment: The json objects will be present in the link i need to connect to the URL and then validate