# RSpec controller spec: How to test rendered JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a simple controller's action of a Rails API

Here's the controller in question:

```
class Api::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    transactions = Transaction.all
    json = TransactionSerializer.render(transactions)
    render json: json
  end
end
```

Here are my specs so far

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::TransactionsController do
  describe '.index' do
    context "when there's no transactions in the database" do
      let(:serialized_data) { [].to_json }

      before { allow(TransactionSerializer).to receive(:render).with([]).and_return(serialized_data) }
      after { get :index }

      specify { expect(TransactionSerializer).to receive(:render).with([]) }
      specify { expect(response).to have_http_status(200) }
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test the response. Something like in this Stack Overflow question [How to check for a JSON response using RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159882/how-to-check-for-a-json-response-using-rspec):

`specify { expect(response.body).to eq([].to_json) }`

My problem is that `response.body` is an empty string. Why is that ?

Comment: What is it that you are expecting in `response.body`? Also, better practice to have `expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)`.

Comment: Because your database in `test` environment is empty.

Comment: Yes the database is empty, so the response should be an empty array. Besides as you can see in the specs, I stubbed the serializer to return an empty array.

Comment: I think that you need to call ```get :index``` in a ```before``` block, otherwise there is not response body.

Comment: Yes it works and it makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what kind of serializer you're using. But, `render` is not a method on an `ActiveModel::Serializer`. Try this instead:

```
module Api
  class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      transactions = Transaction.all
      render json: transactions
    end
  end
end
```

If your `TransactionSerializer` is an `ActiveModel::Serializer`, Rails will, by convention, just use it to serialize each Transaction record in the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

And, test it like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::TransactionsController do
  describe '#index' do
    context "when there's no transactions in the database" do
      let(:transactions) { Transaction.none }

      before do
        allow(Transaction).to receive(:all).and_return(transactions)

        get :index
      end

      specify { expect(response).to have_http_status(200) }
      specify { expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq([]) }
    end
  end
end
```

Part of the problem here might have been that you weren't actually calling `get :index` until `after` the tests ran. You need to call it before the tests run.